# When does Play Store update Google Chrome?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, application-autoupdate

Some visitors to my organisations web site are affected by [this Chrome v61 bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=765524) which is reported fixed in v62.

The [Wikipedia Chrome version page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_version_history) shows v62 was released 19 October 2017 on Android.  Google Play store states Chrome [current version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome) varies by device.

Play Store on our test devices running Android 4 (Galaxy S3), 5 (J2), 6 (Nexus 5) and 7 (Huawei P10) all report Chrome v61 as being the latest available.

Is there a typical or published propagation time for Google Chrome updates ?

It's been a couple of weeks since v62 release date so we are wondering if or when these updates will be installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is no definite answer concerning established time for Google Chrome updates (and/or other related apps), but the general one is that it **varies depending on the developers' schedule**.

Of late, Chrome Chrome updates have been released on a **[staged rollout](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149?hl=en)**.

> What happens here is that with a staged rollout, the update reaches
>   only a percentage of users, and various factors are used to target
>   such a small "audience" and may include (but not limited to):

- device type
- OS version
- specific users e.g in certain selected regions
- other criteria

*Note this is different from independent developers who have no option of targeting eligible users*

So it's a waiting game until the next batch of root reaches your specific device. I see you have quite a number of OS versions you mentioned but as I explained, is Google who select the eligibility criteria and it's according to their schedule.

However an alternative workaround, would be using other markets will the latest releases of Chrome 62 e.g [apkmirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome/#variants) and sideloading it.